# Difference between number/10 and number*0.1 in java

Tags: java, types

I've been working on an interview question for 1.5 hours and could not find the bug in my Java program.
And then I found what the problem was, which I don't understand (don't pay attention to the values, there were others, it's about the types):

```
int size=100;
Integer a=12;
if(a >= size/10)...
//didn't work
```

is different than

```
if(a >= size*0.1)...
//worked
```

I understand that there is a conversion, but still, how is it possible that with a=12, if(a>=size/10) returns false?

Why is that?

Comment: [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) or [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) or [SMBC: Welcome to the Secret Robot Internet](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2999).

Comment: Have you tried at least what is the output of size/10 and size*0.1 before asking the question??

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I can hardly imagine a less helpful comment. How does a 90-page math-heavy description of the minutia of floating-point help someone who obviously hasn't realized yet that int / int is an integer division?

Comment: @PascalCuoq The second link is a 90 page math-heavy description. The first goes to Wikipedia, and the third is a web comic. Finally, there is already an answer that explains the `int` results.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch … and none of them has anything to do with the first, obvious reason why `int / 10` is different from `int * 0.1`.

Comment: What I wonder about is why either of the `if` statements would fail. `12 >= 10` is true as much as `12.0 >= 10.0` is.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I guess `a` is probably a `double`, say `1.4` and `size` an integer, say `15`... In that case `size/10 == 1` and `size*0.1==1.5`.

Comment: I see your edit. Are you absolutely sure these are the values you are actually using in your program? It works just fine on my machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/10` is *integer division*. While `*0.1` first converts the first operand to a `double` and performs a *floating point multiplication*.

If you use the `/10`, and the operand is `14`, it will result in `1` indeed, `14/10=1.4` but integer division rounds this *down*. Thus `29/10=2`.

If you use `*0.1`, the Java compiler will first convert the value of `size` to a double, thus `14.0` and then muliplies it with `0.1` resulting in `1.4`.

On the other hand it's not all beaty that comes out of floating points. `float` and `double` can't represent every integer, and round off after computation.

For the given values for `size` however, it will result in the effect because `100` is a multiple of `10` and a `float` or `double` is capable of representing any integer value in the range from zero to hundred.

Finally `/10` is not always an integer division: if the first operand is a floating point (e.g. `14.0d/10`), the compiler will convert this to a *floating point division*.

**Short version:**

- `int/int` is an *integer division* that rounds down to the nearest (lower) integer.
- `int*double` is a *double multiplication* that - with rounding off errors - results in the floating point value, nearest to the correct result (with decimal digits).

Comment: thank you for this great answer, my question is under-rated, but it was not so obvious, now I understand.

Comment: @Yoav42: Well I did +1, I guess the problem is that most books/courses don't spent much time on how numbers are represented, while this has a big impact on how to solve such problems.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested here:

```
public class a {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 100;
    int a = 12;

    System.out.println((a >= size / 10) ? "OK" : "Failed?");
  }
}
```

And it worked. I don't think this is your real problem. Probably it's in another part of your code.

Comment: Yes, that's because, as argued before, `100` is dividable by `10` and `a` is an integer. It starts failing if `a` is a floating point and `size` is not dividable by `10`.